# How to calculate a sum using a geometric series

Tags: summation

How to calculate this with a simple calculator.

$$\sum_{i=20}^n=59 0.1\cdot600\cdot1.04^{60-i} = \text{ ?}$$

I tried this but it's wrong. Can somebody please tell me where I made a mistake?

```
=0,1*600*1,04^(60-20)*(1-1,04^60-(59-20+1)/1-1,04)
```

With this I obtained `8577,91017` and apparently the right answer is `5929,59217958`

Comment: Just so we're clear, all of your commas are the same as decimal points, correct? Also, what is $n$?

Comment: \sum_{i=20}^{n=59} 0.1*600*1.04^(60-i) = ? I mixed "," and "." my bad. The , is for decimal

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange. Does the sum go from $i=20$ to $i=59$ ? If so, you should omit the $n$ to avoid confusion.

Comment: Hint : Compute the easier sum $$\sum_{i=1}^{40} 0.1\cdot600\cdot1.04^i$$ having the same value. You can even simplify that to $$60\sum_{i=1}^{40} 1.04^i$$

Answer (score 2):

Some of the notation is a bit off, but I believe what you want is

$$\sum_{i=20}^{59}0.1\cdot600\cdot1.04^{60-i}=60\sum_{k=1}^{40}1.04^k=60\left(1.04^{41}-1.04\over1.04-1 \right)={60\cdot1.04\over0.04}(1.04^{40}-1)=1560(1.04^{40}-1)$$

which indeed computes to the given right answer.  The key is that as $i$ runs from $20$ up to $59$, $60-i$ runs from $40$ down to $1$.

Comment: Thank you :) It is more clear

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).